# Django Slug raising error NoReverse Match

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls, slug

I am working on a django project(Django v2.0) which has users from different groups, this group is set up within the user profile. I would like to make the website more personal and have the user's group at the start of the website's url (added in through a slug), after they login.

Ideally once they login they would then be redirected to the right page with that slug at the beginning of the url. Within the login page I access the user's group, this group is called and will from now on be referred to as troop, to minimise confusion with Django groups. Here's my login class post view where I retrieve this:

```
def post(self, request):
    def normal_user(user):
        return user.groups.filter(name='Normal_User').exists()

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        if normal_user(user):
            redirecting_url = 'accounts:home'
        elif user.is_superuser:
            redirecting_url = 'admin:index'


        slug = user.userprofile.troop

        return redirect(redirecting_url, slug=slug)
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        error = True
        args = {'form': form, 'error': error}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

In this case I am trying to access the url "account" which I have called "home" and is in my app "accounts".

My home function in views.py in the app accounts has this code:

```
def home(request, slug):

args = {'user': request.user}
return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', args)
```

I do not want to do anything with the slug except display it in the url.
My template view looks like this:

```
 <div class="container">
 <br>
 <h2><strong>Your Progress:</strong></h2><br>
 <h3>
 <a href="{% url 'accounts:progress_page' slug=instance.slug %}" style="color:red"><strong>50% progress</strong></a>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar bg-danger progress-bar-striped progress-bar- 
animated" role="progressbar" style="width:50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria- 
valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">50%</div> </div>
</div></h3>
<br><br>
{% endblock %}
```

I also have a link to 'home' within my navbar and I link it in the similar fashion than the link above, using {% url 'accounts:home' slug = instance.slug %}
I'm currently having the following error:
"NoReverseMatch at /BC/account/
Reverse for 'home' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/account/$']"
The slug in this case is 'BC'.

My urls.py look like this:
In the root folder:

```
main_urls = [
path('leaders/admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('account/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts'))

]


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls', namespace='home_page')),
    path('login/',  include('login.urls', namespace='login')),
    path('<slug:slug>/', include(main_urls))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And my urls.py in my accounts app looks something like this:

```
app_name="accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home")
]
```

Sorry for the long description, but I've been reading every possible site/video I could find on Django slugs and have not been able to find anything which works yet. Could someone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking around my code I found something which works. This is as it seems to be that I should be able to have views which take in a slug argument whilst still working if the slug is empty. To fix this all I did was change the `slug` part in my view function definitions to `**kwargs`. 
Then I added a varaiable which accessed what the slug was and passed that through my templates for when I have a link.
For example:

```
def home(request, **kwargs):
    slug = request.user.userprofile.troop
    args = {'slug_arg': slug}
    return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', args)
```

My links in my templates then look like this: `{% url 'accounts:home' slug=slug_arg %}`

---

**Edit**
I have found that the problem was that during my rendering, I should be able to pass through the slug, and in this case `slug=instance.slug` was not working and was sometimes coming up as being empty. However if I have it at `slug=request.user.userprofile.troop` then this works without having to accept an argument from the view.

---

In having said such, I am unable to do this for the admin site as I do not know how to access the views.py for the admin and thus add the parameter to take in the slug.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression for your url requires the slug to be at least one character long. However, the exception you're getting suggests that the *troop* name (which is used as the `slug` named argument) is empty:

```
Reverse for 'home' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}'
```

If the user isn't required to have a *troop*, in which case you want to just redirect him to `/accounts/` instead of `/troop/accounts`, I suggest you add a separate URL for just `accounts/$`, or tweak the regular expression to allow an empty *troop*.

Comment: Hi Samu, thank you for you suggestion. I added a url for if it was just `account/$` but sadly this does not seem to fix the problem. This is as the slug is in the url, but it seems my view does not pick it up. Although if I remove the `slug` argument in my view I do get an error saying: `home() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug'`, so  I think something is going through.

Comment: If you add a second regex for the same view that does not match the same number of arguments as the view accepts, this is the error you get. Either supply a default value for slug to your view method, or provide a default value in the URL definition.